# How to pass a Data Flow from one package to another

Tags: ssis

I'd like to pass a Data Flow from one package to another for the following reasons:

1. It would help in refactoring common
   logic in SSIS packages.
2. It would enable concurrent
   development of larger SSIS packages.

At first glance, the Execute Package Task sounded promising, but it looks like I can only pass fairly simple variables in and out of the package.

Is there a way to do this using SSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cozyroc.com is a third party tool that can do this I believe.

Comment: Cozyroc's data flow source/destination is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks William!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of clarity Paul, are you talking about 1) code reusability or 2) allowing the results from one DFT to be used in another DFT?

The first you can't do in "native" SSIS I believe - a set of DFT modules that you can call from other packages, but I would approach it as building a set of packages that are quite simple

- initialision routines
- DFT
- cleanup

Then having variables passed to the child package that are (e.g.) table to be processed, variable(s) to be selected from the source table.

It would requrie a very clever schema and some clever thinking about what the common DFT would do. But I think it would be possible.

The second is not possible without jumping through a few hoops - like saving result sets to temporary tables then re-reading the tables into later DFTs, but then you would loose the data actually flowing through the task.